# Akka Chat app for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, websocket, socket.io, akka

I am writing an iOS chat client.
Server is using([Akka](https://akka.io)) with java.

URL to hit is provided:
example:
akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@efyduatio.XYZ.com:5222

I tried using many ways in Socket/WebSocket to connect to the server:

```
var socket: SocketIOClient = SocketIOClient(socketURL: NSURL(string: "https://efyduatio.XYZ.com:5222")!)

var socket: SocketIOClient = SocketIOClient(socketURL: NSURL(string: "http://efyduatio.XYZ.com:5222")!)

var socket: SocketIOClient = SocketIOClient(socketURL: NSURL(string: "tcp://efyduatio.XYZ.com:5222")!)

var socket: SocketIOClient = SocketIOClient(socketURL: NSURL(string: "wss://efyduatio.XYZ.com:5222")!)
```

I am unable to connect to the server, whereas the android client has Akka library, and same url connects perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SocketManager` instead of `SocketClient`

```
guard let url = URL(string: "https://efyduatio.XYZ.com:5222") else { return }
let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: url)
let socket = manager.defaultSocket

socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) {data, ack in
    // do stuff upon connection
}

socket.connect()
```

Comment: Function nw_protocol_boringssl_handshake_negotiate_proceed: line 387 Handshake failed. Disconnecting the session.
 TIC TCP Conn Failed 
SURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9800)